# Chamar API via Post com JS ou JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, http-request

Pessoal alguém poderia me ajudar dando um exemplo de como consumir uma API que retorna um JSON assim como essa API abaixo:

https://console.faceplusplus.com/documents/6329465

Pessoal implementei o código abaixo podem me ajudar não esta retornando nada nem erro.

```
$('.teste').click(function() {


      $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect",
        data: {
            api_key: 'M...s',
            api_secret: 'y...0',
            url: 'http://emotions.pushsistemas.com.br/web/train/mmi/alegria/1.png'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("saida",JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
    });

  });
```

Comment: O site não funciona para dar códigos prontos. Vc precisa tentar fazer e se tiver algum problema vc recorre aqui. Ou então vc pode pesquisar na busca algo relacionado que tem muito material já publicado.

Comment: Eu so queria um exemplo mas, obrigado de qualquer forma.

Comment: consegui implementar a requisição poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Retire o `JSON.stringify` e faça o que a resposta do Rodrigo diz que o retorno será um JSON de onde vc pode pegar os dados que deseja.

Comment: Oi @Sam eu removi e fiz as alterações a requisição acontece mas, mesmo assim não aparece no log.

Comment: mas aparece a palavra "saida" que vc colocou?

Comment: também não @Sam creio que não entrou em sucess mas no navegador da 200 e vejo a saída assim como o Rodrigo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86625/discussion-between-sam-and-adilmar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Segundo a documentação nos dados para passar um `URL` da imagem a propriedade deve ser `image_url` e não `url`.
2. Troque o tipo do `dataType` de `jsonp` para `application/json`

***Código final:***

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect",
    data: {
        api_key: 'M***s',
        api_secret: 'y***0',
        image_url: 'http://emotions.pushsistemas.com.br/web/train/mmi/alegria/1.png'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("saida",JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    dataType: 'application/json',
});`
```

Fiz o teste e obtive o seguinte resultado:

```
{
    "image_id": "CxX5j9mXrorIFJ/336gFbQ==",
    "request_id": "1543955895,b7599a1a-e67b-4298-9dc5-566c3d13758e",
    "time_used": 1707,
    "faces": [{
        "face_rectangle": {
            "width": 296,
            "top": 316,
            "left": 152,
            "height": 296
        },
        "face_token": "e17f055212b25d1837004bff48d21226"
    }]
}
```

> [image: Evidência]

Comment: Obrigado, estou tento erro de cors Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente)

Comment: Pessoal consegui aqui mas não consegui fazer isso sair no formato json no console.log alguém tem ideia de como fazer ?

Comment: @Adilmar geralemente existem configurações a ser feitas no painel de chaves da API.